# speech to text macOS swift playground

Tags: swift, macos, speech

I am trying to get speech to text working on my mac in swift. I found a few articles but they are all for iOS. I'm trying to follow this one:
http://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/

So far this is my code in Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
import Speech

while true {
    microphoneButton.isEnabled = false  //2

    speechRecognizer.delegate = self  //3

    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in  //4

        var isButtonEnabled = false

        switch authStatus {  //5
        case .authorized:
            isButtonEnabled = true

        case .denied:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("User denied access to speech recognition")

        case .restricted:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("Speech recognition restricted on this device")

        case .notDetermined:
            isButtonEnabled = false
            print("Speech recognition not yet authorized")
        }

        OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
            self.microphoneButton.isEnabled = isButtonEnabled
        }
    }
}
```

It comes up with the error, "No such Module Speech"

My questions are, is it possible in macOS? Is it possible in playgrounds?

Thanks in advance,
Jersh

Comment: It seems like the [Speech library](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) is only available on iOS, so you're out of luck with SFSpeechRecognizer.

Comment: That would work as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the [Speech library](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) is only available on iOS, so you're out of luck with SFSpeechRecognizer. `NSSpeechRecognizer` could be an alternative but requires you to give a list of words for it to recognize from (rather than recognizing from any arbitrary word).

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the first results when I search for speech to text on MacOS. But the accepted answer appears to be outdated and the Speech framework is now supported as of MacOS 10.15+. Here’s the main page from Apple for the Speech framework that indicates it supports Mac: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech

The link for “Recognizing Speech in Live Audio” takes you to an iOS-specific example. However, going to the SFSpeechRecognizer class page lists the required steps for setting it up on any supported platform: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer

For the processing live audio bit, it recommends using this object: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechaudiobufferrecognitionrequest

The docs around this don’t seem to cover capturing an audio stream. I found this for capturing an audio stream in the required PCM format: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/soundanalysis/classifying_sounds_in_an_audio_stream

Hopefully that’s enough to point people in the right direction. But when I setup a working code example, I’ll update this answer.